Can a photon in superposition be "partially measured"?
I'm a bit of a physics layperson and have been learning the basics of quantum mechanics from various resources online. I've come up with a thought experiment that I can't figure out the answer to, and would appreciate any guidance!
The high level idea is: When we have something in a superposition of many states, and then take a measurement which shows it is not in one of them, does it remain in a superposition of the other states, or does it fully collapse to a single state?
The thought experiment is a variant of the double-slit experiment, but with three slits instead of two:

Immediately behind the first slit, we have a detector. By "immediately" we mean there is no space for a wave to propagate between the slit and the detector.

Behind each of the other two slits, I'd like to put something that "delays" a photon for, let's say, ten seconds, without measuring it. I think the simplest way to do this would be a giant tube (like a fiber-optic cable) ten light-seconds long that curves in a big circle and exits near its entrance, but maybe it could also be something that absorbs the photon and re-emits it later?

The two "delay" components then exit pointing at the standard detector for a double-slit experiment, ie a wide-area detector set at some distance from the exits.


I guess my preliminary question is, is the above set-up theoretically possible? Or am I missing anything fundamental that makes, say, the "delay" component physically impossible?
Assuming it is possible, suppose we now emit a photon into this set-up. My understanding is that one-third of the time (or maybe not exactly one-third, but some calculatable percentage), the detector on the first slit detects the photon, and so there's no detection on the other.
My question is, what happens the rest of the time? In other words, suppose after five seconds, the first detector has not gone off: What is the state of the system? I can see two possibilities:

The fact that we have observed no detection through the first slit means the photon has been measured, and this means its superposition has collapsed to having gone through a specific one of the other two slits, and it is now halfway through that slit's delay mechanism. If this is the case we'd expect to see the photon to show up five seconds later in a pattern centered on one of those two slit's exits.

The photon has "partially collapsed" to a superposition of having gone through the other two slits. In that case, we'd expect an interference pattern on the detector behind the other two slits' exits, again five seconds later.


Which of these happens? Or does something else happen entirely?

Are you familiar with the concept of weak measurement?

@nielsnielsen No! Got any links or references where I could learn about it?

yes, there is a book called Through Two Doors At Once by Anil Ananthaswamy which contains a treatment of it.

The answer to ‘does it remain in a superposition of the other states, or does it fully collapse to a single state?’ is that it remains in a superposition of the other states.

So this means we would see an interference pattern in the experiment I described?


I guess my preliminary question is, is the above set-up theoretically possible? Or am I missing anything fundamental that makes, say, the "delay" component physically impossible?

So you want to delay the light coming through the two other slits. A long optical fibre will do that.
Why do you want to delay - is it to create a time window in which the fact of non-detection in the first slit will imply that light is somewhere in the optical fibres? This implication is problematic, because before some detection happens, we do not have two options for the two remaining slits, but 4 options: one for each slit, and one for "photon hasn't arrived yet". When it arrives, the quantum state can very well be in symmetric superposition of all three, even if we are expecting the detector in the third path to click and it hasn't clicked for a longer time. The fact it hasn't clicked does not imply that light went the other two ways; maybe it hasn't arrived yet.


The fact that we have observed no detection through the first slit means the photon has been measured...


So no, we can't use "measured" this way. Absence of evidence here does not mean there is evidence of presence elsewhere; here, it does not mean evidence of photon somewhere in the other paths. Photon detection times are random, with broad distribution, so one detector being silent for a longer time than average does not imply that there was a photon through the other paths.

...and this means its superposition has collapsed to having gone through a specific one of the other two slits

At what time exactly would you do such an update of the quantum state? No, there is no reason to collapse randomly into one of the two remaining paths. The natural thing is to use the superposition of all three all the time until some new fact requires we update the quantum state. Before that, all three regions should be treated symmetrically.
Collapse (projection) is indicated when we learn a fact about the system which implies its quantum state has to be different from what it was before. No such thing is learned while waiting for any detector to click, before the first click.


The photon has "partially collapsed" to a superposition of having gone through the other two slits. In that case, we'd expect an interference pattern on the detector behind the other two slits' exits, again five seconds later.


Again, there is no reason to think there was such a collapse. If we run the experiment long enough,  so many photons come through, I would expect the detection pattern on the screen behind the slits to show interference fringes due to two other slits without a detector; and if the first slit and its detector transmit light while detecting it, the net pattern should have also random diffuse background with no interference fringes due to this detected and transmitted light.

Thanks for the insight! I didn't realize there was a variation in the time-to-detection as well as the detection location. But if the slits are, say, 1 meter from the emitter, the odds of a detection after 5 seconds must be much lower than within the first second, right? So shouldn't a lack of detection after 5 seconds allow us to conclude something about the quantum state - like the amplitudes of the other two slits should be higher now?

@DanStaley > "the odds of a detection after 5 seconds must be much lower than within the first second, right?" I don't think this has to be so. Maybe no light packet/photon was emitted at all in 5s; afaik one can't launch emission of photons/ individual wave packets of smallest energy at desired time, it's assumed to be random to a large extent. But you're right that a long non-detection says something about state of light; I just don't think this is enough to apply collapse at any definite time.

@DanStaley I don't know the best way to think about this. One way is that packets come randomly in time, but are quite symmetrical in space, so all three slits are with equal weight. Then long non-detection may be due to 1) wave packet came through the first slit, but detector there did not click (no detector is 100% efficient); 2) wave packet came and went through the other slits; 3) wave packet went in a different direction and ended up in slit mask or went undetected elsewhere; 4) no light packet has come yet. Theoretically one could consider superpositions of all these options.

Thanks for your insight. I definitely was originally imagining the double-slit experiment set-up as "push a button to emit a photon", now I see the time of emission is uncertain. I'll see if I can think of a different way to "partial measurement", though the other answers seem to have answered the high-level question.

When we have something in a superposition of many states
....in other words, you are assuming we have some arbitrary quantum system (which is always in a superposition of many states, in many different ways).  Your assumption is akin to assuming we have some number, which is a sum of other numbers.  The "which is" phrase adds nothing.  It's not wrong but it suggests confusion.
 and then take a measurement which shows it is not in one of them, does it remain in a superposition of the other states, or does it fully collapse to a single state?
False dichotomy.  There is no difference between a superposition of states and a single state, just as there is no difference between a sum of numbers and a number.
What happens when you take a measurement is that the state collapses to an eigenstate of the measurement you took.  That eigenstate is the projection of the original state onto the subspace corresponding to the outcome of your measurement.

The high-level question was indeed a bit handwavy, which is why I provided a specific scenario with a concrete question about the what distribution of detected photons we would see.

But based on your statement "That eigenstate is the projection of the original state onto the subspace corresponding to the outcome of your measurement", it sounds like you're saying that the answer to my question is "yes"? Because the state collapses to a subspace, but not necessarily a 1-dimensional one?

Yes, exactly.  The state collapses to a subspace but not necessarily a 1-dimensional one.   In fact if your measurement has only two possible outcomes (e.g. "yes, the photon is at location X", or "no, the photon is not at location X") then the "yes" and "no" eigenspaces span the entire state space, which has as many dimensions as the number of possible locations for the photon.  So they can't both be one-dimensional.

Thanks! One last question - I know some linear algebra, but haven't heard the term "eigenstate" before. I know we view a quantum state as a complex vector, so I would guess that the eigenstate is an eigenvector of some linear (unitary?) operator? My question is - if that's correct, what is that operator?

@DanStaley :  To every observable there corresponds a hermitian (not unitary!) operator.  The eigenspaces of that operator correspond to the possible outcomes of the measurement.   A measurement with outcome X causes the state of the system to "collapse", which means it gets projected onto the X-eigenstate of the operator corresponding to the measurement.  As for which operators correspond to which measurements, that is a longer story than can be addressed in a comment.
